# Geting some garbage value on the second index

Tags: c, pointers, garbage

I'm trying to calculate HCF in C with pointers.

int-type-Pointer ptr points to an array of integers.
The inputs that i have given are 30,60,18,a. And here "a" is to terminate the list of integers and breaks off the "while".

I tried the debug mode, and found the values:

```
*ptr = 30
*(ptr+1)= -1163005939  //the garbage that i'm talking of. 
*(ptr+2)= 60
*(ptr+3)= 30
```

while what i should get are 30, 60,18.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

int* ptr=(int*) malloc( sizeof(int)* 50);
int input=0;
int smallest;

printf ("Enter the numbers (press any alphabet when you're done )\n");

    while (1)
    {   input++;     

        if (input==1 && scanf("%d", ptr))  // the first number is stored in smallest
        {smallest = *ptr; continue;}

        if (!scanf("%d",ptr+input ))   // if the input is a character , scanf says 0, 
        {input--;                      //! makes it 1, and we jump out of  the loop
            break;}                     

        if (smallest > *(ptr+input))  // swapping
        { smallest += *(ptr+input);
            *(ptr+input) = smallest- *(ptr+input);
            smallest= smallest- *(ptr+input);
        }
    }

// code for determining the HCF
char c;

if (smallest <=0)
{
printf("", scanf("%c",&c ), printf("Answer is 0")); // it will print that the answer 
exit(0);                                            //is 0 then waits for you to 
}                                                   //press any key and then it exits

//if smallest greater than 0

int i=2;
int HCF=1;
int j;

for (; i<smallest/2; i++)
    { for (j=0; j<=input;j++)

         // this is where the problem is suspected 
         //as i ve seen in the debug mode 
         //it gives results divides the garbage value to i

       {if (! (*(ptr+j)%i == 0))   // if the number stored in the location is not 
          break;                   //divisible by i, then leave that number i 
        }                          //and check for the next i 

        if (j>input)
        HCF *= i;
    }

    printf( "", scanf("%c", c), printf("The HCF is %d ", HCF)); 
    free(ptr);

}
```

So what is the problem?
And i didnt want to allocate the 50 ints memory. I wanted to just use the pointer wildly without any allocation. I know its bad practice but i just want to apply it . Is that any harm to other programs? How?

Comment: I could not compile this without a number of warnings of missing headers and incorrect return types. Compile with `gcc -Wall` or similar, depending on your compiler, and then fix what you see.

Comment: Your problem? Indentation. Even with allocation, you cannot use pointers "wildly". Harm to other programs? Not on modern OSes (for processes in user space).

Comment: You don't even have to enable warnings, just read the ones you already get (this is not meant to imply you shouldn't enable them).

Comment: You probably didn't want this: `if (input==1 && scanf("%d", ptr))` you wanted this: `if (input==0 && scanf("%d", ptr))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's garbage because you never write anything to it.  Look at this code

```
while (1)
{   input++;     

    if (input==1 && scanf("%d", ptr))  // the first number is stored in smallest
    {smallest = *ptr; continue;}

    if (!scanf("%d",ptr+input ))   // if the input is a character , scanf says 0, 
    {input--;                      //! makes it 1, and we jump out of  the loop
        break;} 

    //code that doesn't assign values to ptr
}
```

by the time you get to `scanf("%d",ptr+input )`, `input` will be `2` if `scanf("%d", ptr)` returned a truthy value.  That's because of this if statement:

```
    if (input==1 && scanf("%d", ptr))  // the first number is stored in smallest
    {smallest = *ptr; continue;}
```

notice how you `continue` here when `input` is equal to `1`? that means that the `while` loop will skip everything else and begin again from the beginning, and the first thing that it's going to do is increment `input` from `1` to `2`.

Comment: I've done following changes.  
 
    for(input=0; ; input++){  
  
       if (input==0 && scanf("%d", ptr))  
         {smallest = *ptr;continue;}

  
       if (!scanf("%d",ptr+input ))      
           {input--;  
             break;}
  
        if (smallest > *(ptr+input))  // swapping  
                { smallest += *(ptr+input);
                  *(ptr+input) = smallest- *(ptr+input);
                   smallest= smallest- *(ptr+input);
  }}

And now on inputting 30,60, 18,36, what i get is 
*(ptr) = 30  
*(ptr+1) = 60  
*(ptr+2) = 30  
*(ptr+3)= 36  

  I dont no where i am doing wrong

Comment: @Lucky try printing the value of `input` too.  Do it at the very beginning of the loop.  That might help you better understand what's going in in your code.

Comment: As i printed the values of input  figured out that i was swapping the smallest values provided to the previously set smallest value. And so 18 always goes missing in the case . Its all done. Thanks a lot.